# Is it possible to miss dreams?

Tags: lost-odyssey

Throughout the game you interact with various objects, people, environments that trigger "dreams". I want to find them all because they're interesting and add to the story, and to satiate my rabid completionism.

**Is it possible to permanently miss any of these dreams during the game, or is it possible to pick them all up late in the game when you can fast-travel anywhere?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not according to this guide [here](http://www.trueachievements.com/viewcomment.aspx?commentid=7708#vch) and from personal experience. I do remember missing a few dreams and used this guide to go back and get them. Didn't have to start another playthrough. It's still a good practice to have guides like this in front of you when playing an RPG like this however, if you are a completionist like myself.

Comment: I would add that there are certain pickups in the game that are much harder to get 100% of if you don't use a guide.  I found many, but ended up falling a few short and didn't have the attention span to go back and research, despite my OCD.